# Deploy multiple web application on different website using Web deploy in TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, webdeploy

I have a solution which have three applications
a. One web application
b. Two web services

I want to host
applicaton on One website A
and services on Another website B

When I am trying to host build using automatic build deployment in TFS, I am getting only one web service. Can anybody tell me how to host these 3 applications.

Following is the build arguments which I am using in build definition

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MsDeployPublish /p:CreatePackageOnPublish=False /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /p:Configuration=Dev /p:MSDeployServiceUrl="https://X.X.X.X:8172/MsDeploy.axd" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site/SampleApplicaion"  /p:UserName="username" /p:Password="password" /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True
```

Thanks,
Ashwani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your arguments you are specifying that all deploys should go to "Default Web Site/SampleApplicaion". The command arguments will override any values you have set in your project configuration and so all apps will be deployed to this IIS website.

Instead you need to set the IIS site in the configuration settings of your project. Then you can specify Website A and B and that setting will be used when running your build.

Comment: Thanks Wouter, but this will require changes on solution level. I can have two build definitions one for website A and other for website B. But now the problem is which project will go to which web site how can I specify that in MSBUILD arguments?

Comment: I run a seperate MSBuild for each project in my Build Script and specify a different destination. I don't think it's possible to build a solution and specify different destinations for each project in it. And the changes are not on solution level but on project level.